# How to cancel or update Outlook meeting?

Tags: c#, .net

I sent Outlook meeting Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook package.Now I want to delete or update those meeting using this NuGet package.Can anyone help me how to update or delete meeting from outlook

```
   try
   {
        if (agendaMeeting != null)
        {
            agendaMeeting.MeetingStatus =
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
            agendaMeeting.Location = "Conference Room";
            agendaMeeting.Subject = "Discussing the Agenda";
            agendaMeeting.Body = "Let's discuss the agenda.";
            agendaMeeting.Start = new DateTime(2018, 12, 31, 15, 10, 0);
            agendaMeeting.Duration = 60;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient recipient =
                agendaMeeting.Recipients.Add("ragithas@abcd.com");
            recipient.Type =
                (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired;
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._AppointmentItem)agendaMeeting).Send();
        }
    }
    catch(System.Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Comment: That is a _horrible_ way of doing error handling.

Comment: the documentation seems to be comprehensive.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitemclass?view=outlook-pia